# Android Failure Post to Facebook wall after SDK upgreade

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have an android app and i just upgraded the Facebook SDK to 3.0 because i needed to show the mobile app installs in the statistics...

After that the Post To Wall function stopped warking

My results of LogCAT are:

```
02-06 03:49:38.893: D/dalvikvm(3226): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 42K, 46% free 3004K/5511K, external 13906K/15688K, paused 19ms
02-06 03:49:42.396: D/dalvikvm(3226): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1281K, 51% free 3697K/7495K, external 13906K/15688K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-06 03:50:05.309: W/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1967 (com_facebook_login_activity_layout) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$layout;
02-06 03:50:05.309: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0003
02-06 03:50:05.319: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0051 in Lcom/facebook/LoginActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
02-06 03:50:05.319: W/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1949 (com_facebook_login_activity_progress_bar) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$id;
02-06 03:50:05.319: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0008
02-06 03:50:05.319: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: dead code 0x000a-0013 in Lcom/facebook/LoginActivity;.onPause ()V
02-06 03:50:05.419: W/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1976 (com_facebook_internet_permission_error_title) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$string;
02-06 03:50:05.419: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0010
02-06 03:50:05.419: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: dead code 0x0012-0026 in Lcom/facebook/AuthorizationClient;.checkInternetPermission ()Z
02-06 03:50:05.439: D/Database(3226): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.antmoves.stardome/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, error message: No such file or directory
02-06 03:50:05.439: D/Database(3226): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.antmoves.stardome/databases/webview.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 45 M, handle: 0x48fa38
02-06 03:50:05.499: D/Database(3226): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.antmoves.stardome/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, error message: No such file or directory
02-06 03:50:05.509: D/Database(3226): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.antmoves.stardome/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 45 M, handle: 0x492808
02-06 03:50:05.599: W/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1943 (com_facebook_close) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$drawable;
02-06 03:50:05.599: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001d
02-06 03:50:05.599: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: dead code 0x001f-002e in Lcom/facebook/widget/WebDialog;.createCrossImage ()V
02-06 03:50:05.599: W/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1977 (com_facebook_loading) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$string;
02-06 03:50:05.599: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0024
02-06 03:50:05.599: D/dalvikvm(3226): VFY: dead code 0x0026-006d in Lcom/facebook/widget/WebDialog;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
02-06 03:50:19.473: D/AndroidRuntime(3226): Shutting down VM
02-06 03:50:19.473: W/dalvikvm(3226): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(WebDialog.java:188)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:339)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:249)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:461)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:209)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:188)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:116)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:97)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.Session.tryLegacyAuth(Session.java:1096)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Session.java:893)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:957)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.Session.openForPublish(Session.java:415)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.openSession(Facebook.java:319)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:313)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:221)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.antmoves.stardome.ShareOnFacebook.loginAndPostToWall(ShareOnFacebook.java:135)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.antmoves.stardome.ShareOnFacebook.share2(ShareOnFacebook.java:121)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.antmoves.stardome.ShareOnFacebook$1.onClick(ShareOnFacebook.java:59)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my class for the facebook is:

```
    private static final String APP_ID = "AppID";
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};
private static final String TOKEN = "Tokken";
private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";
private Facebook facebook;
private String messageToPost;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    restoreCredentials(facebook);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.share_on_facebook);
    AlertDialog.Builder alert_box=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert_box.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    alert_box.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           if (isNetworkAvailable())
               share2();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
      });
    alert_box.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           doNotShare2();
       }
      });
    alert_box.show();
    setContentView(R.layout.share_on_facebook);

    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    if (facebookMessage == null){
        facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
    }
    messageToPost = facebookMessage;
} 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
        return editor.commit();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
    = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (activeNetworkInfo != null)
      return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
  return false;
}
public void doNotShare(View button){
    finish();
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void share(View button){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void share2(){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}
public void doNotShare2(){
    finish();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void loginAndPostToWall(){
    try {
        facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
    }

    //facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("Error!!");
        }
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Error!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null){
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
}
private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

any idea how this could be resolved????

Thanks everyone for your time...

Comment: The 3.0 SDK includes resource files where as 2.0 was just a jar file. Here it looks like those resource files were not included as part of your apk. How are you including the 3.0 SDK, and how are you building your app? Make sure the 3.0 SDK is included as an Android Library in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an issue with the Facebook SDK in your app:

`03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string`

`02-06 03:50:19.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3226): at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(WebDialog.java:188)`

This means that it can't find the R$string referenced from the Facebook SDK in your final APK. Check to ensure that you're including the necessary class files.